# Angular JS deep linking will refresh view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I'm going to try my best to explain this problem. I am also new to Angular so bear with me.

I have two routes that use the same template...

```
ExampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/logbook/following', {
        templateUrl: 'views/surf.html',
    })

    .when('/logbook/following/:surf_id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/surf.html',
    })
}]);
```

with two controllers

```
AppControllers.controller('LogbookController', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

    $scope.surfs = null;

    // Get feed
    $http.get(RestURL + 'feeds?filter=following' ).success(function(data) {

        if(typeof $routeParams.surf_id == "undefined") {

            if(data.length > 0) {

                $location.path('/logbook/following/' + data[0].id);
                $scope.loadSurfDetail(data[0].id);
            }
        }

        $scope.surfs = data;
    });
});


AppControllers.controller('SurfController', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

    $scope.loading = false;

    // Load surf
    $scope.loadSurfDetail = function(surfID) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.selectedSurf = null;

        // Get surf
        $http.get(RestURL + 'surfs/' + surfID).success(function(data) {
            $scope.selectedSurf = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };

    if($routeParams.surf_id) {
        $scope.loadSurfDetail($routeParams.surf_id);
    }
});
```

using this template file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="logbook col-md-3" ng-controller="LogbookController">
        <h1>Logbook</h1>
        <ol class="surfs-feed">
            <li data-id="{{feedSurf.id}}" ng-repeat="feedSurf in surfs" class="surf">
                <a href="#/logbook/following/{{feedSurf.id}}">
                    <strong>{{feedSurf.user.first_name}} {{feedSurf.user.last_name}}</strong>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="surf col-md-9" ng-controller="SurfController">
        <p class="alert alert-info" ng-show="loading">
            Loading...
        </p>
        <div class="surf-detail" ng-show="selectedSurf">
            <pre>
                {{selectedSurf | json}}
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that when I load a deep link URL, ie. /logbook/following/:surf_id it will use the same template as /logbook/following (adove) and that will cause the logbook feed to be regenerated each time you load up a new surf. So each time you load the surf, the logbook "blinks" and regenerates.

I would like to know how people have tackled this problem without refreshing the feed of surfs and just updating the detail panel on the right hand side...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app config, inject $locationProvider and set its html5Mode parameter to true. Then, route changes will not cause the page to refresh.

```
ExampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/logbook/following', {
        templateUrl: 'views/surf.html',
    })

    .when('/logbook/following/:surf_id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/surf.html',
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```